# Rails 4: AJAX contact form nested in another class's view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

My app has `Programmes` for which I want users to be able to submit `InfoRequests` via an AJAX form. (In the background, that will trigger sending an e-mail with the form inputs to the programme's coordinator.)
`Programmes` have pages (rendered via their `show` action) and that's where I want to include the form for the `InfoRequest`. Once the request is sent, I want the user to see positive feedback, and the form inputs should become read-only, so that the user can still see what he/she submitted, but not directly submit again.
I struggle to make the AJAX work and I am at a loss what's wrong. I get to the line `"InfoRequest not delivered"` (see below), which is expected as I cannot send mails in my dev environment. But the AJAX callbacks specifically don't trigger, so I see no reaction in the form (nor the `window.alert` calls I put in the code, except for the `"init_info_request"`).

Here is what I currently have - any help is appreciated. I am more than happy to re-structure stuff as long as it makes things leaner and simpler.

---

**programmes_controller.rb**

```
class ProgrammesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @programme = Programme.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @info_request = InfoRequest.new(:programme => @programme)

    ...
  end
end
```

---

**info_request.rb**

```
class InfoRequest < MailForm::Base

  attribute :first_name,          :validate => true
  attribute :last_name,           :validate => true

  attribute :programme

  ...

end
```

---

**info_requests_controller.rb**

```
class InfoRequestsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @info_request = InfoRequest.new
  end

  def create
    puts "**********> InfoRequest#create"

    @info_request = InfoRequest.new(params[:info_request])

    @info_request.programme = Programme.friendly.find(params[:info_request][:programme_id])

    @programme = @info_request.programme
    @coordinator = @info_request.programme.coordinator

    @info_request.request = request

    if @info_request.deliver
      puts "**********> InfoRequest delivered"
    else
      puts "**********> InfoRequest not delivered"
    end
    end
  end
end
```

---

**programmes/show.html.erb**

```
...
<%= render partial: 'info_requests/new' %>
...
```

---

**info_requests/new.html**

```
<%= render 'info_requests/new' %>
```

---

**info_requests/_new.html**

```
          <%= form_for(@info_request, remote: true, id: 'info-request-form') do |f| %>
            <input type="hidden" name="info_request[programme_id]" value="<%= @info_request.programme.id %>" />
  ... other form inputs ...
                      <button type="submit" id="info-request-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success">Yes, request information now!</button>
          <% end %>

<script>
  var init_info_request;

  init_info_request = function() {
    window.alert("init_info_request");

    $('#info-request-form').on('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings) {
      window.alert("ajax:beforeSend");
      $('#info-request-submit').text("Sending request...");
    });

    $('#info-request-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      window.alert("ajax:success");
      $('#info-request-submit').text("Sent!");
    });

    $('#info-request-form').on('ajax:complete', function(event, xhr, status) {
      window.alert("ajax:complete");
    });

    $('#info-request-form').on('ajax:error', function(event, xhr, status, error) {
      window.alert("ajax:error");
    });

  }


  $(document).ready(function(){
    init_info_request();
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by nesting the route:

```
resources :programmes
  resources :info_requests, shallow: true
end
```

This means that we are placing the id of the programme in the actual path instead. Which means that our route is now restful and descriptive.

```
class InfoRequestsController
  # use a callback instead of repeating yourself.
  before_action :set_programme, only: [:new, :index, :create]

  # GET /programmes/:programme_id/info_requests
  def index
    @info_requests = @programme.info_requests
  end

  # optional
  # GET /programmes/:programme_id/info_requests/new
  def new
    @info_request = @programme.info_requests.new
  end

  # POST /programmes/:programme_id/info_requests
  def create
    @info_request = @programme.info_requests.new(info_request_attributes) do |i|
      i.request = request
    end
    @coordinor = @programme.coordinator

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        if @info_request.deliver
          head :created
        else
          head :unproccessable_entity
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_programme
    @programme.includes(:info_requests)
              .friendly.find(params[:programme_id])
  end

  def info_request_attributes
    @params.require(info_request).permit(
      :foo, :bar, :baz
    )
  end
end
```

I would really recommend using the [MailCatcher gem](https://mailcatcher.me/) for development. Its a simple SMTP server that instead of delivering email just catches them. You can then just open `http://127.0.0.1:1080` in a web browser to see the "outgoing" emails in a GUI.

Now we can setup our form

```
# views/info_requests/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for([info_request.programme, info_request], id: 'info-request-form', data: { remote: true, type: 'json' }) do |f| %>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success">Yes, request information now!</button>
<% end %>
```

Don't call your partial `_new` if you also have a `new` template as its confusing.

```
<%= render 'info_requests/form', info_request: @info_request %>
```

And lets setup an ajax handler:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '#info-request-form', function(e, xhr, status){
  window.alert( "Thanks!" );
  $(this).attr('disabled',true);
}).on('ajax:error', '#info-request-form', function(e, xhr, status){
  window.alert( "Please try again." );
  $(this).attr('disabled', false);
});
```

First off we are delegating the event handler from the document - this makes it idempotent so that it works properly with turbolinks.

Since we are returning the correct HTTP response codes jQuery UJS will fire either the `ajax:success` and `ajax:error` tabs. I would encourage you to learn how to use the network tab in the web inspector instead of debugging with alert statements.

Comment: In general learning how to use the inspector in the browser and the log in rails instead of using puts/alert will make you a lot more productive.

Comment: Thanks! How do I use the log to check in which "branch" of the code I end up? That's the main reason I use puts (and alert) in such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. There were two issues.

1. Via jQuery, I was screening for callbacks on `#info-request-form`, because that's the ID I set via the parameter in `form_for`. Turns out that the `id` parameter is ignored. Instead, the form's automatically-set ID was `#new_info_request`.
2. I added a `views/programmes/_save.js.erb`. It is processed when the form is submitted, so then I can validate the form elements and show feedback. (I could probably alternatively do that in the callbacks in `_new.html.erb`.)

**Now it works!**

Two comments/questions to the answer by max:

- The reason I did not use a shallow route is that `InfoRequests` will at a later stage be possible for other resources as well, not just `Programmes`. I assumed I didn't need nesting specifically for AJAX and it turns out that I actually don't. Whether or not I'll keep using the `InfoRequest` class as is etc. is still a bit open for now.
- Do you object only to calling the partial `_new`, or do you object to it being there in the first place? Because the reason there's a partial is that I need to be able to render it from `Programme#show`. Wouldn't know how to do it without a partial.